# How do I fix my 3-way light to work with my Ring floodlight cam and my dining room dimmer switch

Tags: light, dimmer-switch

When I moved in, an indoor 3-way light switch existed.  One to turn on overhead fan, one for the dining room light & one for backyard porch light.  My handyman replaced my porch light with a Ring floodlight/cam/motion detector & put a new dimmer switch on the dining room. The Ring switch is always on.   All went well for 4 years.  Now for some reason after using the dining room switch at night, my Ring light starts strobing off/on like Morse code!  I was able to reset it but happened again once I used the dimmer switch for dining room again.  Any ideas what’s gone wrong?

Comment: You mean a set of 3 separate switches, correct? A "3-way" switch is a single switch with an extra switch terminal to permit 2 switches to control one light.

Comment: "3-way" is a very specific term that normally refers to "two switches that can both control one light (or other device)". I *think* you are here using it to mean "3 switches, each controlling a separate light or other device, with the 3 switches in one box". Please clarify and then we can continue with diagnosis. In addition, if you can upload pictures showing the wiring in the switch box(es), that would help a lot.

Comment: "3-gang" is the term you're looking for.

Comment: I do mean 3 switches each controlling a separate device.  Thank you.